# After re-naming commerce policy, not able to load customer listing and customer detail page in Bizfx tool

Tags: sitecore-commerce

After re-naming commerce policy file, not able to load customer listing and customer detail page in Bizfx tool because json data containing older reference in database and with below error in commerce authoring log file.

> INFO DeserializeEntityBlock: Deserialize entity failed, trying to
> migrate. Error=Could not find type
> 'Plugin.HttpExtension.Policies.CancelationPolicy' in assembly
> 'Plugin.HttpExtension, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.

> ERROR SQL:block:findentitiesinlist.Error:
> Message=Error resolving type specified in JSON
> 'Plugin.HttpExtension.Policies.CancelationPolicy,
> Plugin.HttpExtension'. Path 'Policies.$values[46].$type', line 1,
> position 19712.|Trace=   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName(JsonReader
> reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member,
> JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
> String qualifiedTypeName)    at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader
> reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member,
> JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
> Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)

As in eCommerce app development cycle, sometimes we may need to re-name policy files.
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through sitecore commerce database table found that policy reference as added in Global database CommerceEntity table.

In CommerceEntity table both old and new policy were present.

After removing older policy reference from CommerceEntity table with sql update query, bizfx tool start loading customer listing and customer detail page and error was also fixed.